# Rails: Item not saving to database (routing with nested resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running into a problem when trying to create a new object using nested resources in Rails. My routing is set up as:

```
resources :coins do
  resources :questions
  resources :events
end
```

When I attempt to create a new event, it does not save. Adding ! to **event.save** gave me an error that says "*Validation failed: Coin must exist*".

I don't have a validation set up for the coin (in the Event model at least, if that is what its referring to). Checking the log file shows the following, which as far as I can tell shows that the correct coin is selected:

```
Started GET "/coins/1/events/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-24 18:52:19 -0500
Processing by EventsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"coin_id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mCoin Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "coins".* FROM "coins" WHERE "coins"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering events/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered events/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_defaults.html.erb (34.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 62.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started POST "/coins/1/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-24 18:54:46 -0500
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dAXQ3uwxR2IN2rbAYD//gulHebIOdZWFPYCKnxcUKTuV4QnUp+SZYHMpZUsGOgEXQjOAnhFUO9MpJkIIAKcQlQ==", "event"=>{"content"=>"LKNA", "link"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "coin_id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mCoin Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "coins".* FROM "coins" WHERE "coins"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Coin must exist):

app/controllers/events_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

I have it set up the same way for my Questions model, as they are almost identical aside from names, and that one works with no issues. I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing incorrectly here.

controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :find_coin

  def index  
    @events = Event.where(coin_id: @coin.id).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @event = current_user.events.build
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save!
      flash[:success] = "Event Saved"
      redirect_to coin_event_path(@coin.id, @event.id)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Event *NOT* Saved!!!"
      render 'new'
      @event.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
  private

    def find_event
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_coin
      @coin = Coin.find(params[:coin_id])
    end

    def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:content, :link)
    end
end
```

model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :coin 
end
```

coin model:

```
class Coin < ApplicationRecord
    validates :link_name, :currency_name, presence: true
    has_many :questions
    has_many :events
end
```

If anyone has any idea what I may be doing wrong or any tips on how to figure it out, I would really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: When you do `@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)` you actually create an event related for the user, and it is not related to the coin anymore. Try to set the coin as well for the event before saving. (`@event.coin = @coin` something like that)

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making an answer for anyone else who needs it and doesn't read comments :)

When you do:

```
@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
```

You actually create an event related for the user, and it is not related to the coin anymore.

Try to set the coin as well for the event before saving:

```
@event.coin = @coin
```

Or you can do it the other way - build the event on the current coin, and then set the user:

```
@event = @coin.events.build(event_params)
@event.user = current_user
```

That way - the `coin_id` will be set automatically because you build an `event` on that `coin`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue adding 'optional: true' to belongs_to method.

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

By default 'belongs_to' require the user_id.

You can use too: 'required: false'.

```
belongs_to :user, required: false
```

Good luck.